# How do I gain enough rep to actually post on this site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, images

How can I gain 10 rep to even post my question?

I need to post an image so I can ask what it is.

Comment: Post a link to the image instead.  If your only question is "what is this?" it is probably off-topic.  We're not an identification service.

Comment: It's done this way to prevent people from posting nekkid pictures.  We have [underage people](http://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) here, y'know.