# Images for low-rep users

Tags: support, suggested-edits, images

Reviewing edits yesterday, I saw one rejected where the editor had tagged a new answer onto an old answer, and uploaded images to use in the answer whilst doing so. I suggested in a comment on a post that they had made that they should post it as a new answer.

This they duly did, but commented back that they couldn't post the images, which they presumably attempted to upload again (I then edited the original links to the images that had been successfully uploaded in the suggested edit into the new answer).

Research has shown that more than 10 rep is needed to post an image, and since this applies to an answer, it presumably applies to a question.

However, it does not seem to apply to an edit, at least of someone else's answer (don't know about question, or own question, or own answer).

If it is to make unwanted processed-meat-type messages (obfuscation so *they* can't find this so easily), shouldn't it apply to edits as well?

I know edits by <2k users are reviewed, but all *they*'d need to do is put "improv indention" in the edit explanation and whack a code-block in, and it'll get through [almost] any review.

Comment: It's not that you can't use images, you just can't upload them, at first. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194994/how-do-i-gain-enough-rep-to-actually-post-on-this-site). It does offer a good reason why it isn't allowed earlier.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard OK, updating...

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: So, wait, users with < 10 rep can't upload images while posting a new question / answer, but they _can_ upload them while suggesting an edit (and, if they're clever enough, copy-paste the URLs into a new question / answer)? That sounds like a bug of _some_ kind to me...